# Error 503 when executing post request from my endpoints API

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm trying to put data into the server from my endpoints API but I get an error that I don't understand when I call the POST request.

My messages class, nothiing special:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from protorpc import messages

class UserCreateResponseMessage(messages.Message):
    """With this message we say if user put to the server was ok"""
    success = messages.BooleanField(1, default=False)

class UserCreateRequestMessage(messages.Message):
    """With this message we pass data to put into the server"""
    phone_number = messages.StringField(1, required=True)
    e_mail = messages.StringField(2, required=True)    
    password = messages.StringField(3, required=True)
    name = messages.StringField(4)
    birth_year = messages.IntegerField(5, required=True)
    birth_month = messages.IntegerField(6, required=True)
    birth_day = messages.IntegerField(7, required=True)
```

My api, a class with just one method that put the fields into a User and tries to save it:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from google.appengine.ext import endpoints
from protorpc import remote

from whis_api_messages import UserCreateResponseMessage
from whis_api_messages import UserCreateRequestMessage
from models import User

@endpoints.api(name='whis_api', version='v1',
               hostname='whisper-by-easierelephant.appspot.com',
               description='Whis API')
class WhisApi(remote.Service):
    """Class which defines Whisper API v1."""
    @endpoints.method(UserCreateRequestMessage, UserCreateResponseMessage,
                      http_method='POST',
                      path='users',
                      name='users.create')
    def users_create(self, request):
      """get the data and call to put the user in the database"""      
      user = User(parent = models.userbook_key())

      user.phone_number = request.phone_number           
      user.e_mail = request.e_mail     
      user.password = request.password
      user.name = request.name
      user.date_of_birth = datetime.date(year=request.birth_year,     month=request.birth_month, day=request.birth_day)
      user.profile_picture_name = 'empty'

      user.put()

      return UserCreateResponseMessage(success=True)

app = endpoints.api_server([WhisApi], 
                           restricted=False)
```

my app.yaml:

```
application: whisper-by-easierelephant
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /_ah/spi/.*
  script: whis_api.app
  secure: always

- url: /.*
  script: main.app
  secure: always 

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
- name: pycrypto
  version: latest
```

The response I get when I try to execute it from apis explorer:

```
503 Service Unavailable

- Show headers -

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "backendError",
    "message": "Internal Server Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 503,
  "message": "Internal Server Error"
 }
}
```

I really don't know what's happening and I'm really desperated. I'm new with endpoints so every advice and recommendation would be appreciated.

Comment: What errors are you getting in the log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I have to import my file 'models' and 'datetime' to whis_api.py.

To see what's happening in your app when you execute it from the explorer, go to https://appengine.google.com, click on your application an then "Logs" and you will see a detailed version of the errors happened during executions on the server.

Comment: Thanks to @WilliamGaul for the question that illuminated me!